LLM not able to parse output using stroutputparser()
I am often getting this error in Langchain agent.I am doing a RAG operation and using Langchain tools and agents. I use AWS services like bedrock and Lambda for the application.
This is How, I have defined agents:
from langchain.agents.initialize import initialize_agent

agent = initialize_agent(
     tools=tools, 
     llm=llm, 
     agent="zero-shot-react-description", 
     verbose=True
)

but I am getting error like:
handle_parsing_errors=True` to the AgentExecutor. This is the error: Could not parse LLM output: ``
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/src/amaHandler.py", line 365, in lambdaHandler
    finalAnswer = agent.run(query)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py", line 180, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 600, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py", line 180, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 383, in __call__
    return self.invoke(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 166, in invoke
    raise e
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 156, in invoke
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1433, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1139, in _take_next_step
    [
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1139, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1178, in _iter_next_step
    raise ValueError(

Also to mention I am not getting this error every time, but like 1/5 times.
My LangSmith shows:
ValueError: An output parsing error occurred. In order to pass this error back to the agent and have it try again, pass `handle_parsing_errors=True` to the AgentExecutor. This is the error: Could not parse LLM output: ` I now know the final answer to the original input.question
<|start_header_id|><|start_header_id|>`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1167, in _iter_next_step
    output = self.agent.plan(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 732, in plan
    return self.output_parser.parse(full_output)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/mrkl/output_parser.py", line 67, in parse
    raise OutputParserException(
langchain_core.exceptions.OutputParserException: Could not parse LLM output: ` I now know the final answer to the original input.question
<|start_header_id|><|start_header_id|>`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/src/amaHandler.py", line 365, in lambdaHandler
    finalAnswer = agent.run(query)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py", line 180, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 600, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py", line 180, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 383, in __call__
    return self.invoke(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 166, in invoke
    raise e
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 156, in invoke
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1433, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1139, in _take_next_step
    [
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1139, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1178, in _iter_next_step
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: An output parsing error occurred. In order to pass this error back to the agent and have it try again, pass `handle_parsing_errors=True` to the AgentExecutor. This is the error: Could not parse LLM output: ` I now know the final answer to the original input.question
<|start_header_id|><|start_header_id|>`

STRoutputparser generated the answer but agent failed
Tried what was told by agent: handle_parsing_error = true
but didn't work out.
Tried to find solutions online but found nothing.
Tried looking into Langchain docs but couldn't find any viable solution .
edits:
tools are like
        tools = [
            createrequestTool,
            projectTool,
            materialTool,
            taskTool,
            generalTool,
            expenseTool,
            transactionTool,
            eventsTool,
            documentTool,
            errorTool,
            budgetTool,
            purchaseorderTool,
            mathsTool,
        ]

    @tool
    def budgetTool(query: str) -> str:
        """Budget tool"""
        response = projectChain.invoke(f"{budgetPrompt}")
        return response


Hi, would be cool to see a bit more code: how do you call the agent, which prompt is triggering the error, how do you parse output with  stroutputparser()

what version of langchain do you have? Also what tools are you equipping this agent with?

@cottontail version - langchain==0.2.1 and tools are custom ones that outputs string/markdown accordingly.

@JohnnyCheesecutter Added more code
